# Why is the below code throwing null pointer exception?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

So I have the following code for a popup window in an activity:

```
private void initiatePopupWindow(String popupText, boolean hasEditText){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) PlayActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View layout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_layout));
    final PopupWindow popupWindow= new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 370, true);
    findViewById(R.id.play_activity_layout).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }
    });

    TextView textPopup= (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvPopupText);
    textPopup.setText(popupText);

   if(hasEditText) {
       EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumber);
       MAX_NUMBER_OF_MOVES = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
   }

    btnClosePopup= (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnClosePopup);
    btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            //finish();
        }
    });
}
```

I get the NullPointerException for this row:

```
MAX_NUMBER_OF_MOVES = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
```

I tried to fix this by searching on the site for ideas but still dont know why it isnt proper.

EDIT:

My popup_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#444444"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10sp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPopupText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:text="@string/under_construction"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClosePopup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etNumber"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvPopupText"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could you show your layout?

Comment: Check if the editText et is in your layout?

Comment: Its in. i edited my question with the popup layout!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use

```
EditText et = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.etNumber);
```

see `layout.` missing.

Note that `getText()` never returns null. So only `findViewById` should raise the NullPointerException.

Comment: Oh that solved the half problem. Now it throws: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" for the same row.

Comment: @Nepo // Your input in `EditText` could be empty. why don't you input `0` or some numeric value?

Comment: @Nepo // your question is only about NullPointerException. not NumberFormatException. you have to use `try` `catch` to handling NumberFormatException to handle it.

Comment: The fact is that the Popup not even popping up, it throws exception when I  want to open my activity... so Im not even able to insert anything there :S

Comment: @Nepo // just define `android:text="0"` at your `etNumber` layout xml file.

Comment: Oh my God, it works. But how can I get a blank edittext when the popup comes up? Thats my last question and I will accept your answer :)

Comment: @Nepo // your `parseInt` method is processed during the popup creation (at `layout.findViewById`). So, move `MAX_NUMBER_OF_MOVES = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());` line into `public void onClick(View v){...}` function. Then it will processed when you click the button.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this:

```
final View layout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_layout));
```

for this other one:

```
// container = get it from param of onCreateView  
final View layout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, container);
...
EditText et = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.etNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

After you've fix the layout.findViewById....

Initialize the EditText to some default value...see the android:text="0" below

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etNumber"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvPopupText"
    android:text="0"
    />
```

And you should also ALWAYS wrap Integer.parseInt("string_value") in a try/catch block in case string_value is not a valid number:

```
try {
    MAX_NUMBER_OF_MOVES = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe_) {
    MAX_NUMBER_OF_MOVES = 5; // Or whatever your default number should be
}
```